# unit-testing boost interprocess client

Tags: unit-testing, boost-interprocess

I have to unit-test a client of a shared memory map constructed using the boost interprocess. It is really awkward to create shared memory blocks for unit-testing. Normally I would use some static memory to simulate shared memory behavior during unit-tests.

I do not see such a possibility in the boost interprocess. What is the established practice for unit-testing clients of the boos interprocess?

Answer (score 0):

There is basic managed external buffer that provides the same API to manage a local buffer:

[basic-managed-external-buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/basic_managed_ext_idm26691.html)